# Jenkinsfile Pipeline errors: “expected a step” and “undefined section”

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Can anyone explain why I get the following errors, and what can be a possible solution for them?

> Running in Durability level: MAX_SURVIVABILITY
>   org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
>   startup failed: WorkflowScript: 43: Expected a step @ line 43, column
>   17.
>                      if (isUnix()) {
>                      ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 71: Undefined section "success" @ line 71, column 5.
>          success {
>          ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 78: Undefined section "failure" @ line 78, column 5.
>          failure {
>          ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 16: Tool type "maven" does not have an install of
>   "MAVEN_HOME" configured - did you mean "Maven M2"? @ line 16, column
>   19.
>                  maven "MAVEN_HOME"
>                        ^
>
> WorkflowScript: 17: Tool type "jdk" does not have an install of
>   "JAVA_HOME" configured - did you mean "null"? @ line 17, column 17.
>                  jdk "JAVA_HOME"
>                      ^

The code in the `Jenkinsfile` is as follows:

```groovy
  pipeline {

        // agent defines where the pipeline will run.
        agent {
            // Here we define that we wish to run on the agent with the label SL202_win
            label "SL202_win"
        }

        // The tools directive allows you to automatically install tools configured in
        // Jenkins - note that it doesn't work inside Docker containers currently.
        tools {
            // Here we have pairs of tool symbols (not all tools have symbols, so if you
            // try to use one from a plugin you've got installed and get an error and the
            // tool isn't listed in the possible values, open a JIRA against that tool!)
            // and installations configured in your Jenkins master's tools configuration.
            maven "MAVEN_HOME"
            jdk "JAVA_HOME"
        }

        environment {
            // Environment variable identifiers need to be both valid bash variable
            // identifiers and valid Groovy variable identifiers. If you use an invalid
            // identifier, you'll get an error at validation time.
            // Right now, you can't do more complicated Groovy expressions or nesting of
            // other env vars in environment variable values, but that will be possible
            // when https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-41748 is merged and
            // released.
            mvnHome = "D:/Tools/apache-maven-3.5.2"
        }

        stages {
            // At least one stage is required.
            stage("Preparation") {
                // Every stage must have a steps block containing at least one step.
                steps {
                    // Get some code from a GitHub repository
                    git 'https://git.ceesiesdomain.nl/scm/rsd/test_automation.git'
                }
            }
            stage('Build') {
                steps {
                // Run the maven build
                if (isUnix()) {
                    sh "'${mvnHome}/bin/mvn' clean test -Dtest=TestRunner"
                } else {
                    bat(/"${mvnHome}\bin\mvn" clean test -Dtest=TestRunner/)
                }
            }
        }
            stage('Results') {
            steps {
                cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE', failedFeaturesNumber: 999, failedScenariosNumber: 999, failedStepsNumber: 3, fileIncludePattern: '**/*.json', skippedStepsNumber: 999
            }
        }
    }
        // Post can be used both on individual stages and for the entire build.
        post {
            success {
                echo "Test run completed succesfully."
            }
            failure {
                echo "Test run failed."
            }
            always {
        // Let's wipe out the workspace before we finish!
                deleteDir()
                echo "Workspace cleaned"
            }
    }

    success {
        mail(from: "jenkins@ceesiesdomain.nl",
                to: "ceesie@ceesiesdomain.nl",
                subject: "That build passed.",
                body: "Nothing to see here")
    }

    failure {
        mail(from: "jenkins@ceesiesdomain.nl",
                to: "ceesie@ceesiesdomain.nl",
                subject: "That build failed!",
                body: "Nothing to see here")
    }

    // The options directive is for configuration that applies to the whole job.
    options {
        // For example, we'd like to make sure we only keep 10 builds at a time, so
        // we don't fill up our storage!
        buildDiscarder(logRotator(numToKeepStr:'10'))

        // And we'd really like to be sure that this build doesn't hang forever, so
        // let's time it out after an hour.
        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES')
    }
}
```

Comment: The very first error refers to the `if` not being valid in a `stage`. The workaround is to use a `script` block around the logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I managed to get it working by trimming back all excess and starting with the pure essentials and iteratively adding steps and configs and running it after each change to verify the workings.

The script I ended up with now is:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
        label 'SL202_win'
    }
    stages {
        stage("Fetch repository") {
            steps {
                git 'https://git.ceesiesdomain.nl/scm/rsd/test_automation.git'
            }
        }
        stage('Run test') {
            steps {
                bat 'cd d:/SL202_Data/workspace/Front-end-SwiftNL/Sanctie_Regressie_Workflows_WCM'
                bat 'mvn clean test -f d:/SL202_Data/workspace/Front-end-SwiftNL/Sanctie_Regressie_Workflows_WCM/pom.xml -Dtest=TestRunner'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            echo 'Test run completed'
            cucumber buildStatus: 'UNSTABLE', failedFeaturesNumber: 999, failedScenariosNumber: 999, failedStepsNumber: 3, fileIncludePattern: '**/*.json', skippedStepsNumber: 999
        }
        success {
            echo 'Successfully!'
        }
        failure {
            echo 'Failed!'
        }
        unstable {
            echo 'This will run only if the run was marked as unstable'
        }
        changed {
            echo 'This will run only if the state of the Pipeline has changed'
            echo 'For example, if the Pipeline was previously failing but is now successful'
        }
    }
    options {
        timeout(time: 60, unit: 'MINUTES')
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My way is to put the `if` or `for` block in a `script {}` block or `dir("") {}` block when using declarative pipelines.